# Simple question about proof by contrapositivity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have to prove the following statement formally,

"if $n$ is an integer and $5n+3$ is even then $n$ is odd"

If we want to prove by contrapositive don't we take the contrapositive of the statement which is,

"if $n$ is even, then $n$ is not an integer or $5n +3$ is odd"

and prove that it is true. And then since the statement are logically equivalent it implies that the initial statement is also true.

How can we prove that if $n$ is even then $n$ is not an integer? It doesnt make sense except if we ignore it, which is like proving a different statement. Or, is the initial statement put together in a wrong way. In other terms, is it simply $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z} (5n+3 \text{ is even} \to n \text{ is odd})$. Hence the contrapositive is, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\left( n \text{ is even} \to 5n+3 \text{ is odd} \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your final idea; the contrapositive is $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, (n\ $is even$ \Rightarrow 5n + 3$ is odd$)$. As you sumised, the integer condition is a separate part telling you where you are working - since it doesn't make sense to talk about "odd" or "even" when not in the integers.

Comment: Don't you think it should be stated differently, like for all n inegers...

Comment: Probably, but I'd read that as "the statement could have been phrased better" rather than it meaning anything different - since certainly "n even" implies "n is an integer". It may just be that writing things in words is never quite as precise as writing them in symbols.

Comment: I agree, a direct translation rarely works.